# how to obtain uppercase \ell

Tags: typography

```
\ell
```

corresponds to

[image]

Is there a symbol corresponding to uppercase `\ell`?

Comment: `$\mathcal{L}$` perhaps?

Comment: \mathcal works.

Comment: The point of `\ell` is to use that letter rather than the (easily) indistinguishable lowercase `l`. In the case of the uppercase `L` there's no confussion so there's no need to use a different glyph. You might be looking for the `\mathcal` or `\mathscr` alphabets, but I just wanted to point that out. If you are writting a normal uppercase ell, there's no need for a special glyph like there is for the lowercase one.

Comment: I guess this question comes from the IEEE standard 1139-1999 which defines phase noise and make note on used symbol as "script ell". However I have already seen pound sign used in rather classy texts. I would use \mathcal{L} with "calrsfs" package as already suggested for this purpose and other \mathcal{L} use would be reserved for linear operators or Laplace transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either the `amssymb` package or the `mathrsfs` package.
If you decide to use `amssymb` use this to typeset a "curly" L:

```
\mathcal{L}
```

If you decide to use `mathrsfs`, you use:

```
\mathscr{L}
```

Regardless of your choice, I recommend that you include

```
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
```

In your preamble, so that you can easily switch all instances of the curly L if you decide you don't like the one you chose.